# Validate and save a ZIP file in Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, zip

I'm writing an app using Flask and one of the things I want in it is the ability to upload a ZIP that conforms to a specific form; as such I have a small function that takes a `FileStorage` object from the form and first unzips it, checks the contents, and then tries to save. There's a problem, however - apparently unzipping it "breaks" the `FileStorage` object, as the following function:

```py
def upload_modfile(modfile):
    if not modfile.filename.endswith('.zip'):
        raise ModError('Incorrect filename')
    mod_path = join(get_mods_path(), secure_filename(modfile.filename))
    if isfile(mod_path):
        raise ModError('File ' + modfile.filename + ' already exists')
    modzip = ZipFile(modfile)
    base_filename = modfile.filename[:-4]
    modzip_contents = modzip.namelist()
    if join(base_filename, 'info.json') not in modzip_contents:
        raise ModError('Could not validate file')
    modfile.save(mod_path)
    return True
```

saves `modfile` as a text file saying `Archive: <filename>.zip`. If I comment out the entire `ZipFile` bit (i.e. everything involving `modzip`), the file is saved just fine.

I'm pretty much brand new to Python and am a little confused as to what to do in this case, save for saving the file in `/tmp`. Should I somehow clone `modfile` by way of some stream? Is there a way of "rewinding" the stream pointer within `FileStorage` that I'm missing?

Comment: this is not a flask question; please post with a proper title and tags..

Comment: I don't know whether it's a Flask/Wurkzeug problem, or a general Python one - that's one of the reasons I came here in the first place. I never really wrote much Python, let alone code that handles file-like objects coming into a webserver, so be a little bit more informative in your comment please.